# How to show that the following relation is transitive (What is the idea?)

Tags: real-analysis, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose we consider the following set 
$$ X = \big\{ (p,q) : p \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{and} \ q \in \mathbb{N} \big\}$$

Define the following relation $$(p_1,q_1) \sim (p_2,q_2) \iff p_1q_2 = p_2q_1$$

We can easily verify that this relation is both symmetric and reflexive. I am having trouble many with transitive. The issue that I am having is we can't really "divide". So what we assume is the following:

Suppose that $(p_1,q_1) \sim (p_2,q_2)$ and $(p_2,q_2) \sim (p_3,q_3)$. This means that the following equations are satisfied:

$$p_1q_2 = p_2q_1$$
$$p_2q_3 = p_3q_2$$

We would like to show that the following equation is satisfied:
$$p_1q_3 = p_3q_1$$

I am kinda lost in how to do that?

Comment: Multiply $p_1q_2 = p_2q_1$
$p_2q_3 = p_3q_2$  together and divide what you don't need.

Comment: @PhilipWhite this specific relation is traditionally taught and proven in order to lead to defining rational numbers and hence division of integers and rational numbers.  At this point in instruction, neither fractions nor division have been defined and so should not be permitted in any such proof for fear of using a circular argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $p_1q_2=p_2q_1$ and $p_2q_3=p_3q_2$ we obtain
$$
(p_2q_2)(p_1q_3) = (p_2q_2)(p_3q_1),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(p_2q_2)(p_1q_3-p_3q_1) = 0.
$$
Hence either $p_2q_2=0$ or $p_1q_3=p_3q_1$.
Since $p_2q_2=0$ only if $p_2=0$, and in this case we must also have $p_3=p_1=0$ by hypothesis, we are still left with the equality $p_1q_3=p_3q_1$.

Comment: how do you obtain $(p_2q_2)(p_1q_3) = (p_2q_2)(p_3q_1)$?

Comment: @Newbie By multiplying the two equations, as suggested also by Philip White.